# Ionic3 Linkedin Native SDK

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, sdk, linkedin-api

I have used ionic native linkedin SDK in Ionic 3 app. I'm using it for Sign in Via. Linkedin. It was working fine till date, but surprisingly it isn't working fine since last 2 days.

IOS version is giving an authentication error for the app. I also got a notification from linkedIn that they're moving to Auth 2.0 soon. Wondering if it has to do anything with this error? Or anyone else facing this issue?

Comment: I think you should report it here https://github.com/zyra/cordova-plugin-linkedin/issues